# Email doesn't send | PHP

Tags: php, forms, email

Could you give me some advice about this code? Im completely new in php and im trying to send email using this form. When I fill form and send it i get message that every thing is fine but i dont get any email.

**HTML**

```
<form action="send.php" id="contact-form" method="post" class="clearfix">           
                    <fieldset class="field-1-3 left">
                        <label>Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" id="Myname" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Your name...';" onfocus="if(this.value=='Your name...')this.value='';" value="Imię i nazwisko..." class="text requiredField m-bot-20" >
                    </fieldset >
                    <fieldset class="field-1-3 left">
                        <label>Email</label>    
                        <input type="text" name="email" id="myemail"   onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Your email...';" onfocus="if(this.value=='Your email...')this.value='';" value="Adres email..."  class="text requiredField email m-bot-20" >
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="field-1-3 left">
                        <label>Subject</label>  
                        <input type="text" name="subject" id="mySubject"  onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Subject...';" onfocus="if(this.value=='Subject...')this.value='';" value="Temat..." class="text requiredField subject m-bot-20" >
                    </fieldset> 
                    <fieldset class="field-1-1 left">
                        <label>Message</label>
                        <textarea name="message" id="Mymessage" rows="5" cols="30" class="text requiredField" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='W...';" onfocus="if(this.value=='Your message...')this.value='';"   >Wiadomosc...</textarea>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="right m-t-min-1">
                        <input name="Mysubmitted" id="Mysubmitted" value="OK" class="button medium" type="submit" >
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['Mysubmitted'])){
        $to = 'myemailhere@gmail.com';
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $from_name = $_POST['name'];
        $from_email = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $header = "From: $from_name <$from_email>";
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);



    }
?>
```

Comment: See your system log or apache log. It's possible you have no mail program on the system.

Comment: But the code is correct?

Comment: Yes, at a glance. Try to give static value to `mail()`, e.g. `mail("youremail@mail.co", "subject", "header", "From: sender@sender.co <A B>")`

Answer (score 0):

While code is free of parse errors (and there are many issues with it, including - but not limited to - undefined variables in case someone submits empty form), not receiving email can be narrowed down to one of two scenarios:

1. No sendmail on system used to run this code (ie XAMPP/WAMP)
2. E-mail ending up in junk/spam email in case that sendmail actually exists.

Please note that (AFAIK) no windows apache/php bundle ships with working sendmail, and that most of the free webhosts limit usage of mail function.